# Basic ntile function to create decile portfolios

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TShTK.jpg

I try to create decile portfolios based on momentum. I use DAX in Germany.

```
dax <- read.csv("DAXclean.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
as.ts(dax)
mom.return <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax),ncol(dax))
mom.decile <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax),ncol(dax))

for (row in 13:nrow(dax))  {

    for (column in 2:ncol(dax)) {
        mom.return[row,column] <- (dax[row-1,column]-dax[row-12,column])/dax[row-12,column]   
    }

    mom.decile[row,column] <- ntile(mom.return[row,2:ncol(dax)], 10)
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

> ```
> "Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, row, column, value = ntile(mom.return[row, 2:ncol(dax)],  : 
>   subscript out of bounds"
> ```

If I remove the following command, everything works fine.

```
mom.decile[row,column] <- ntile(mom.return[row,2:ncol(dax)], 10)
```

I can't see what the problem is.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ntile(mom.return[row,2:ncol(dax)], 10)` returns a vector, `mom.decile[row,column]` is a single cell.

Comment: Now it worked! Thank you!